# Is there a free monitoring application which can run in a Servlet Container?

Tags: monitoring

I'm not the first person to ask ServerFault to reccomend a monitoring application, however I have some slightly unusual criteria. I'm a developer who reluctantly needs to manage a bunch of systems - it's not something the sysadmins where I work are willing to assist with.

And unfortunately because my role in this organization is that of Develper and not Administrator I only have very limited access to the kinds of system where we might host a monitoring server. I cannot ask for any new kinds of system which have not been previously been allocated to our team. Getting new boxes, operating systems & web-servers would all require agonizing change-management paperwork. Welcome to the big-corporation!

All of our servers are based on Windows and they all run Servlet containers (mostly Apache Tomcat 7). I do not have access to any Linux boxes or Apache HTTPD servers.

I'm looking for a monitoring system which can:

- Run the master-node within Tomcat (sort of like the way Hudson/Jenkins or Sonotype Nexus runs). That would exclude quite a few mainstream applications like Nagios. This would also rule-out Hyperic since it requires JBOSS.
- My ability to configure the Tomcat servers is very restricted - so while I might theortically be able to run PHP based applications on Tomcat I'd have trouble finding a sysadmin willing to help me do this. I do not have the right permissions to change this kind of thing. That means the solution most probably has to be JVM-based.
- Our applications are mostly Java & Python. We'd ideally like to be able to implement custom monitoring plugins in Python. We'd like the application to be very good at monitoring JVM stuff (like Hyperic) .
- The kinds of things we want to monitor are the condition of computers (e.g. disk-space, number of page-faults per second) and the condition of our apps (e.g. whether the result of a query indicates a result which is out-of-date). We are not interested in network monitoring (e.g. routers, bandwidth).
- Most importantly: Our organization hates paying for stuff. It's got to be free!

So, any suggestions. Does any monitoring server fit my requirments? Are there any almost-fits?

FYI, all our servers are Windows 2003 64bit. All our nodes are Windows XP 32bit. The platforms we care about are Oracle Java & Python 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Verax NMS](http://veraxsystems.com/en/products/nms) matches all your criteria and it's free up to 25 elements so you may give it a try. It allows for developing custom plugins and it’s cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

OpenNMS is a generic monitoring solution that is Java based. It come with Jetty, but you can install it in Tomcat.

Comment: OpenNMS seems impressive - however it also seems to primarily be a network monitoring tool. Does it have the application monitoring features of Hyperic - that's what I want.

Comment: I never user Hyperic. From what I've read they are complementary and often installed together.